# How do I retain an objects key name outside of scope of "for in"? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Question: How do retain the key name after a for in look exits. If I assign the key string to a variable outside of the scope of "for in" it turns into a number. is there any way to prevent this and maintain the key name? Thanks

Example:

```
var lastItem = undefined;

function getKeyNames(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            lastItem = i;            
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            alert (lastItem);
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
alert (lastItem);
```

The alert inside the function (and inside the for in) outputes the actual string name of the key, but when I alert outside of the function, I get a number. Any Ideas how to retain the string name of the key? Just to make it clear I'm not talking about the value of an object, but the actual name of the key.

Comment: That code is incomplete. Where do you call `getKeyNames()`?

Comment: Your indentation after the first "if" statement leads to a confusing syntax error (too many closing curly braces).  Can you fix that?

Comment: Also, how is the "getObjects" function defined?

Answer (score 2):

Works fine:

```
var foo = { foo : 22, bar : 42 };
for(var i in foo);
alert(i); // "bar"
```

What, exactly, are you passing to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks fine. After `getKeyNames` is called, `lastValue` will hold the last key found in the object.

However, your example does not call `getKeyNames`, so the `alert(lastValue)` should alert "undefined".

If you ARE calling it somewhere, and you find that `lastValue` contains a number, well it's probably because your object contains a number.  For example, `for (var i in ['a','b','c'])` will iterate "length", "0", "1", "2".